# meaning of back slash at the end of the every line in .js file for html tags

Tags: javascript, html

I was going through .js file and found html tags with backslash at end of everyline. Can some one please tell me why its there?

I have added the complete code. Please let me know why back slash is there.

for example

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#nav").html(
    "<hr class='menubegin' />\
     <div id='menu'>\
        <ul>\
            <li><a href='fawcettHome.htm'>Home</a></li>\
            <li aria-haspopup='true'><a href='#'>Courses &#9662;</a>\
                <ul>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='Courses.htm'>Courses</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='CSE681.htm'>CSE681-SMA</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='CSE686.htm'>CSE686-IP</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='CSE687.htm'>CSE687-OOD</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='CSE775.htm'>CSE775-DO</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='CSE776.htm'>CSE776-DP</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='CSE784.htm'>CSE784-SS</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='Code.htm'>Sample Code</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='OfficeHours.htm'>Office Hours</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='Courses.htm'>Program Plan</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='SoftwareTrack.htm'>SW Track</a></li>\
                </ul>\
            </li>\
            <li aria-haspopup='true'><a href='#'>Core Tech &#9662;</a>\
                <ul>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='CoreTechnologies.htm'>Core Technologies</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='../CoreTechnologies/Cpp.htm'>C++</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='../CoreTechnologies/Cpp.htm'>C++/CLI</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='../CoreTechnologies/CSharp.htm'>C#, .Net</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='../CoreTechnologies/Sockets.htm'>Network Prog</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='../CoreTechnologies/ThreadsAndSynch.htm'>Threads</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='../CoreTechnologies/Win32SystemProgramming.htm'>Win32 Sys</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='../CoreTechnologies/WindowsProgramming.htm'>Win GUI</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='../CoreTechnologies/XML.htm'>XML</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='Mathematics.htm'>Math</a></li>\
                </ul>\
            </li>\
            <li aria-haspopup='true'><a href='#'>Directories &#9662;</a>\
                <ul>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='../'>Handouts</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='../Coretechnologies/'>CoreTech</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='../CSE681/'>CSE681-SMA</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='../CSE686/'>CSE686-IP</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='../CSE687/'>CSE687-OOD</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='../CSE775/'>CSE775-DO</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='../CSE776/'>CSE776-DP</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='../CSE784/'>CSE784-SS</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='../SummerProjects/'>Summer Prj</a></li>\
                </ul>\
            </li>\
            <li aria-haspopup='true'><a href='#'>Research &#9662;</a>\
                <ul>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='Research.htm'>Research</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='ResearchStatement.htm'>Research Statment</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='ResearchCode.htm'>Research Code</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='SWMatrixCrossPlatformDev.htm'>V.Appaduri</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='http://www.lcs3.syr.edu/faculty/fawcett/handouts/research/bolazar/main/index.html'>K.Bolazar</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='SoftwareMatrix.htm'>R.Ghosh</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='VoiceActivatedRecording.htm'>J.Goddard</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='http://www.lcs3.syr.edu/faculty/fawcett/handouts/research/MuratsResearch/MuratsDefense/StructuralModelsForLargeSoftwareSystems.htm'>M.Gungor</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='KayaDefense.htm'>M.Kaya</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='AspectOrientedProgramming.htm'>R.Krishnan-Chittur</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='SelfHealingSoftwareMatrix.htm'>A.Krishna</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='Test2.html'>M.Mohammed</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='SWMatrixModelDrivenDev.htm'>T.Patel</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='ComputingWithGPUs.htm'>P.Pratt-Szeliga</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='SoftwareRestructuring.htm'>S.Singh</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='EnhancedDebuggingThruVirtualization.htm'>R.Wilson</a></li>\
                </ul>\
            </li>\
            <li class='left' aria-haspopup='false'><a href='Notices.htm'>Notices</a></li>\
            <li aria-haspopup='true' class='left'><a href='#'>EECS &#9662;</a>\
                <ul>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='GradOrientation.htm'>Orientation</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='StudentPictures.htm'>Student Picturess</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='StudentCultures.htm'>Student Cultures</a></li>\
                    <li aria-haspopup='false'><a href='Graduates.htm'>Graduates</a></li>\
                </ul>\
            </li>\
        </ul>\
    </div>\
    <hr class='menuend' />"
  );
});
```

Comment: <li><a href='fawcettHome.htm'>Home</a></li>\ see the backslash at the end

Comment: Please rephrase your question; this telks us nothing (example would be **GREATLY** appreciated.) As would be a source site.

Comment: And that is not JavaScript, it's HTML.

Comment: Possibly be line-continuation? Backslash followed by newline indicates a line continuation in C

Comment: This is not HTML. This is a string in another language intended to be output as HTML. In this other language, I suspect, allows the string to span multiple lines (an example of this would be JavaScript strings). If it were HTML, you would see backslashes on your web page.

Comment: Yes the tag was in .js file

Comment: @Amadan : Can you please explain why backslash is being used.

Comment: I did. JavaScript strings can only be on a single line. However, you can "cancel" a newline in JavaScript by preceding it directly with a backslash. Thus, `a = "foo` newline `bar"` is invalid JS; `a = "foo\ ` newline `bar"` is identical to `a = "foobar"`. EDIT: @Isaiah has a good point; the question is mislabeled as HTML when it is, in fact, about JavaScript, and the code is not sufficient to clearly communicate the question.

Comment: @Unbreakable Like I said, line continuation. If you listened to my advice about an example, I could've easily told you. For istance, suppose you want to write a string but want to wrap it on multiple lines on. You can use the backslash to achieve this. Your edited question's example does not follow the guideline of being the **minimum** needed code; we need more code; we need to know the context of the code.

Comment: @Amadan : I have added the complete code.

Comment: Too late, we already figured out and answered you :D But yeah, thanks, that's what the question should have looked like in the first place. (It's okay to abbreviate, as long as you don't leave out anything important, though.)

Comment: @Amadan : But all the line are complete in itself right? Unlike the example you gave. In your example I understand that "foobar" needed to be together but its not the case in the code I just pasted. Everyline is complete in itself. Please help me. I am kinda confused.

Comment: It is literally changing the contents of #nav's html attribute.

Comment: So I should have a thumb rule that whenever I am writing HTML tags in Javascript code and I want to go to next line I should give one backslash..Am I right?

Comment: Everything from `"<hr class='menubegin />` to `<hr class='menuend />'"` is a single JavaScript string. It does not matter if it contains `"foobar"` or HTML markup; until and unless it is added to the DOM, it's just a string. On the other hand, note that e.g. `$(document).ready(function() {` line does not end in a backslash; it is not a string, and does not need to have its newline canceled.

Comment: @Amadan  : Now I understood your point perfectly. Many Thanks. :) Appreciate your help and patience. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code represents a JavaScript string object containing raw HTML. The `\` character allows newlines to be inserted in the string without the need of manual concatenation.